# There's a glitch when adding numerals to a line CSV (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, csv

All of the number 6's in column 6 (Item(5)) should be deleted, and the rest of the numbers should be increased by 1. However, when the process is completed, I check the file and the file is unchanged.

```
Dim liness As New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv"))
            For Each line As String In liness
                Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)
                Do
                    If item(5) = 6 Then
                        liness.Remove(line)
                    Else : Exit Do
                    End If
                    Exit Do
                Loop
                Console.WriteLine("Have you already entered the next school years, year 3's? (y/n)")
                Dim year3s As String = Console.ReadLine
                If year3s = "Y" Or year3s = "y" Then
                    For i As Integer = 1 To liness.Count - 1 'this will read to the end of the array list once
                        If item(5) > 3 And item(5) < 6 Then
                            item(5) = item(5) + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                ElseIf year3s = "N" Or year3s = "n" Then
                    For i As Integer = 1 To liness.Count - 1 'this will read to the end of the array list once
                        If item(5) > 2 And item(5) < 6 Then
                            item(5) = item(5) + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                File.WriteAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv", liness)
                Exit For
            Next
            Exit Do
        ElseIf enter.Key = ConsoleKey.End Then
            Console.Clear()
            adminmenu()
        End If
```

Comment: `line.Split(","c)` is not how you parse a CSV file. Consider using a 3rd party framework, such as KBCsv. Regarding your code, the `Do` loop is useless, because it always ends with `Exit Do`. You could've had just one line instead `If item(5) = 6 Then liness.Remove(line)`. Regarding your `For` loops, the iteration variable `i` is never used, which makes them useless as well. If you want an answer, please explain what you are trying to do in plain English. Thanks. This `year3s = "N" Or year3s = "n"` is usually written as `year3s.ToUpper = "N"`.

Comment: Example CSV file:
aaaaaa,bbbbb,cccccc,dddddd,eeeeee,5  'the 5 should upgrade to 6
fffffff,gggggggg,hhhhhhh,iiiiiii,jjjjjj,6 'this record should be deleted

Comment: So you want to modify a CSV file... okay. Could you please update your question with more information? Include the original file contents and the one you expect to be after modification.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the 'item' array, but not the 'liness' list.  When you write the new 'liness' list to the file, any changes you made to the 'item' array are ignored.

Also, you are writing the 'liness' list back to the file for *every* loop iteration - this has to be wrong - you probably want to do that *after* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't condone using the `Split()` function for parsing CSV data, I'll leave that part alone here in order to highlight other improvements in the code:

```
Dim minYear As Integer = 2
Console.WriteLine("Have you already entered the next school years, year 3's? (y/n)")
If Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim() = "Y" Then minYear = 3

Dim NewLines = File.ReadLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv").
                  Select(Function(l) l.Split(","c) ).
                  Where(Function(l) Integer.Parse(l(5)) <> 6 ).
                  Select(Function(l)
                             Dim x As Integer = Integer.Parse(l(5))
                             If x >= minYear Then x += 1
                             l(5) = x.ToString()
                             Return String.Join(",", l)
                         End Function).ToList()
File.WriteAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv", NewLines)
```

Comment: In the 'Where(function)' line I receive this message "Input string was not in a correct format.", could you also explain the code, since I'm clueless when it comes to Functions; in fact, I have never used them before.

Comment: The error means you have cases where the 5th item in your data cannot be parsed to an integer.

Comment: Cheers, it consists of some blanks.

Comment: I can't place any If statements etc. Like I said I'm clueless when it comes to functions, could you help me out; I know you have helped me far enough, but I would highly appreciate it.